# A Geometry Inequality

Tags: geometry

Let $D$ be a point in $ABC$. It is clear that $AB+AC>DB+DC$. Can one give a nontrivial lower bound for $d=AB+AC-DB-DC$ in terms of $AD$ and $BC$?

As pointed out, it seems that $d>\min\{k_1\cdot AD, k_2\cdot\frac{AD^2}{BC}\}$ for some constants $1<k_1, k_2<2$. Not sure if this is true, or there is any sharper estimate.

[image]

Comment: Lower Bound = 0

Comment: Just let the point D approach A. to see the result

Comment: I'm fairly sure the lower bound is $\sqrt{BC^2-4AD^2}-BC$, but I don't yet have a watertight argument.

Comment: If $BC$ is small, then your bound is $0$?

Comment: Oops, I meant $\sqrt{BC^2+4AD^2}-BC$. My hypothesis is that the minimum $d$ is attained when $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$, and $AD$ is perpendicular to it.

Comment: This seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

The initial question suggested that maybe $d>(\overline{AD})^2/\overline{BC}$. But one can easily find counterexamples with $d<(\overline{AD})^2/\overline{BC}$; in fact, one find counterexamples with $d<\epsilon\cdot(\overline{AD})^2/\overline{BC}$ for any arbitratrily small $\epsilon>0$: let $\overline{BC}=1$; $\overline{AD}=x$; $\overline{AB}=\overline{AC}=x^2$. Then, $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{d}{(\overline{AD})^2/\overline{BC}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x}{x^2}=0$.

Comment: In your setup, when $x$ is large, $d\approx 2x$ hence $d>AD$; when $x$ is small, $d\approx 2AD^2/BC$.

Comment: @HaoranChen yes, I was thinking of $x$ being large ($x\to\infty$...). Am I missing something? Or are you saying that your initial formula can be changed into something like $d>c\cdot \min (AD, 2AD^2/BC)$ for some $c$?

Comment: Your estimate looks promising, although I don't know.

Comment: @HaoranChen I was just saying that the initial guess by itself does not work.